# Rust MongoDB set unique fields

Tags: mongodb, rust

How to set a unique field in the mongodb rust implementation?
Are you supposed to use `create_index()`?

```
async fn create_id_fields(client: Client) -> Result {
     let a = doc! {"my_id" => "1"}.unwrap;
     client
         .database(DB_NAME)
         .collection(COLL_NAME_TICKET)
         .create_index(a, unique = true)
         .await;
 }
```

Thanks for any hint!

Answer (score 3):

```
async fn create_id_fields(client: &Client) {
    let options = IndexOptions::builder().unique(true).build();
    let model = IndexModel::builder()
        .keys(doc! {"number": 1})
        .options(options)
        .build();
    client
        .database(DB_NAME)
        .collection::<Raffle>(COLL_NAME_RAFFLE)
        .create_index(model, None)
        .await
        .expect("error creating index!");
}
```

...so this is my solution but do i have to use the 'builder'?

Comment: it seem yes since it is the only pubic method available in `IndexModel` and `IndexOptions`

Answer (score 0):

To add to DZWG's answer, you may need to add a type to the `1`.

```rust
async fn create_id_fields(client: &Client) {
    let options = IndexOptions::builder().unique(true).build();
    let model = IndexModel::builder()
        .keys(doc! {"number": 1u32})
        .options(options)
        .build();
    client
        .database(DB_NAME)
        .collection::<Raffle>(COLL_NAME_RAFFLE)
        .create_index(model, None)
        .await
        .expect("error creating index!");
}
```